# Pandas Drop Duplicates Across Groups

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a dataframe in which I would like to remove duplicates only across groups and only once.

```html
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
1  1  1  1  Group 2
2  1  1  1  Group 2
3  1  1  1  Group 2  
4  3  8  3  Group 2
5  1  1  1  Group 1
```

In the above dataframe I would want the following output:

```html
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
2  1  1  1  Group 2
3  1  1  1  Group 2  
4  3  8  3  Group 2
```

For each cross group match (across group 1 and 2) if there is a paired match, remove it. Note: if there is a duplicate paired match both would be dropped, as long as there is a pair across groups.

Additional example for clarity:

```html
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
1  1  1  1  Group 2
2  1  1  1  Group 2
3  1  1  1  Group 2  
4  3  8  3  Group 2
5  1  1  1  Group 1
6  1  1  1  Group 1
```

In the above dataframe I would want the following output:

```html
   A  B  C  D
0  1  0  2  Group 1
3  1  1  1  Group 2  
4  3  8  3  Group 2
```

Any help with this is much appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't one of the lines with `1 1 1` in the output belong to group 1 ?

Comment: Yes, index 1 and 5 are dropped. Index 1 is from Group 2 and index 5 is from Group 1.

Comment: Why isn't index 3 dropped ? Sorry, this is a bit confusing

Comment: I want to drop pairs across groups. So although there are 4 "matches" (indices 1, 2, 3, 5), there is only 1 match across groups. ( I chose to drop index 1 from Group 2, but any single match from Group 2 could have been dropped)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification ! I understand now. But I do not know how to do it easily, other than checking each group. I have a feeling you may be wanting to do something wrongly, because if you only drop once, you can still be left with duplicates across groups, so I don't see why the dropping is useful. Can you please state your ultimate goal, maybe there's an easier way to do it ?

Comment: yes, I want to drop any pairs across groups. If there are additional matches (even if it is the same match) across groups, they would also be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

> Firs select duplicated rows on your subset, here: ['A','B','C'] and save as df1. Then groupby this new DataFrame by your groups, here: col 'D'.
> Now for each group, find the index of the first row. Indexes are the same as main dataframe, df. So you can easily drop the row by drop_index value

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'A' : [1,1,1,1,3,1,1], 
        'B' : [0,1,1,1,8,1,1],
        'C' : [2,1,1,1,3,1,1],
        'D' : ['Group 1','Group 2','Group 2','Group 2','Group 2','Group 1','Group 1']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df1 = df[df.duplicated(['A','B','C'],keep=False)]
df2 = df1.groupby('D')
min_duplicate_rows = df2.A.count().min()

for group, data_list in df2:
    for i in range(min_duplicate_rows):
        drop_index = (data_list.index)[i]
        df = df.drop(drop_index)
df
```

Comment: Thank you, Nazanin. You're on to something here, but this code only drops the first paired value from the dataframe. I am exploring what you have provided above.

Comment: Your welcome! I thought it should drop one duplicated row in each group. Its a little confusing :)

Comment: I updated the code. It groups duplicated rows, then find the group with min len and save the length as 'min_duplicate_rows ' and then drop 'min_duplicate_rows in each group.